# Array like function for a statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a statement that returns a single number for a date. What I want to do is to be able to execute the statement across a range of dates and get a value for each date.

```
select dbo.GetItemMTDIssues(inmastx.fac, inmastx.fpartno, inmastx.frev, '6-01-2019') 
as MTDiss from inmastx where fpartno='ANF-10-6313-102'
```

This is how the results look for a single date that I'm getting with my current statement. **6-01-2019**

```
|MTDiss|   
  600
```

This is the expected results that I want over a range of dates like **6-01-2019 - 6-05-2019**

```
|MTDiss|   
  600   
  450   
  375   
  700   
  300
```

Also including the function if it's helpful.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetItemMTDIssues]
    (@fac char(20), @partno char(25), @rev char(3), @currentdate datetime)
    returns numeric (15,5)
    as

    begin
        declare @returnval as numeric (15,5)

        set @returnval =
        isnull(
        (select sum(fQty) 
                from intran 
                where ftype = 'I'
                and month(fdate) = month(@currentdate)
                and year(fdate) = year(@currentdate)
                and fac = @fac
                and fpartno = @partno
                and fcpartrev = @rev)
        ,0.0) * -1

        return @returnval
    end
```

Comment: Added information to get a better idea @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need first to create the range, and the below t-sql will do that.

```
declare @startDate datetime='6-01-2019'
declare @endDate datetime='6-05-2019'

;with DateRange as (
select @startDate [date]
union all
select DATEADD(day,1,[date]) [date] from DateRange where [date]<@endDate
)
select * from DateRange
```

we can test it and see the result to confirm that this is the range we want.
note:if you need to jump by month or number of days other that go day by day you only need to change the code in the DATEADD.

Now we would need to update your function to take the start and end of the range and let it use all the range dates , I think something like the below will help:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION [GetItemMTDIssuesRange]
(   
@fac char(20), @partno char(25), @rev char(3), @startDateRange datetime, @EndDateRange datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    with DateRange as (
    select @startDateRange [date]
    union all
    select DATEADD(day,1,[date]) [date] from DateRange where [date]<@EndDateRange
    )
    --select * from DateRange
    select (isnull(sum(fQty),0.0) * -1) MTDiss
                    from intran 
                    inner join DateRange on year(fdate) = year(DateRange.[date]) and month(fdate) = month(DateRange.[date]) 
                    where ftype = 'I'
                    and fac = @fac
                    and fpartno = @partno
                    and fcpartrev = @rev
                    group by DateRange.[date]
)
GO
```

Please check it.

if you dont want to change the function this below may help too:-

```
declare @startDate datetime='6-01-2019'
declare @endDate datetime='6-05-2019'

;with DateRange as (
select @startDate [date]
union all
select DATEADD(day,1,[date]) [date] from DateRange where [date]<@endDate
)
select dbo.GetItemMTDIssues(inmastx.fac, inmastx.fpartno, inmastx.frev, DateRange.[date]) 
as MTDiss from inmastx,DateRange
 where fpartno='ANF-10-6313-102'
```